# how to 302 redirect a request, unless its for a particular subdomain/folder?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, forwarding

Basically I want to redirect requests for Domain1.com to Domain2.com, but if the request is for Domain1.com/blog (or /blog/) not redirect at all, and stay on the Domain1.com domain. This is only for this particular folder/directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#redirect to domain2 if on domain1.com and path doesn't start with /blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=domain1.com
RewriteCond $0 !^blog
RewriteRule .* http://domain2.com/$0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) around `HTTP_HOST` above your `RewriteRule` doing the redirect.  You can even write it for the one you don't want to redirect for, and negate it.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=Domain1.com
```

Note that you can have multiple `RewriteCond`s, but each grouping (one or more) will only apply to the very next `RewriteRule`*.

Comment: Im trying this but getting a redirect loop on the /pics folder

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =http://www.domain1.com/blog/
    Redirect 302 / http://www.domain1.com/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=http://www.domain1.com/blog/
    Redirect 302 / http://www.domain2.com

Comment: @GrapeCamel - this RewriteCond will compare only against the hostname / domain name.  You can't include `/blog` with it - you should include that as part of the associated `RewriteRule` below this `RewriteCond`.